# Python np array can't read my negative values

Tags: python

I'm working on a project that should do the following:
"Make a Python program that can find diagonal edges in an image.
Input: Greyscale image
Output: Binary image where the diagonal edges are white (255) and the rest of the pixels
black (0)"

This is the [image: original picture]

And this is my [image: current output]

It's not exactly what I'm looking for and I think I found the problem. My np.array (SobelKernel) does not use the negative values when multiplied with pixelValue (checked with a print). Any idea how to fix that?

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


img = cv2.imread('LENNA.JPG')
height = img.shape[1]  
width = img.shape[0] 

out = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)

SobelKernel = np.array([[2, 1, 0],
                        [1, 0, -1],
                        [0, -1, -2]], np.int8)    

for y in range(1, height-1): 
    for x in range(1, width-1): 
        temp = 0

        for j in range(2): 
            for k in range(2):
                pixValue = img[x+ j - 1][y + k - 1]
                kernelValue = SobelKernel[j][k]
                temp = temp + pixValue*kernelValue
                #print(Sobelkernel[j][k])
        out[x, y] = temp 

cv2.imshow('test', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I believe you are not looping through your whole kernel. Shouldn't it be range(3) instead of range(2)? range(2) = 0,1 and not 0,1,2.

Comment: Ah thank you! This helped a bit but I'm still not quite getting what I want. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your resulting image may go outside the boundaries of `int8`.

Save your result in a `out = np.zeros(img.shape, np.int16)` instead, and then work on values below `0` or above `255`.

Then after you handle the values outside the range, cast the array back to `np.unit8` before you save it (otherwise, it will be considered as a 16bits image, not a 8bits one).

Comment: If I do so the whole window just gets black. If I change my values to below or above 255 it's stays black or changes to white (without detecting edges)

Comment: But then you need to turn the type back to `unit8` before saving the image.

Comment: Not totally sure how to cast it back (where to put it). I'm completely new at python, sorry.

Comment: You can use `astype(np.unit8)` or simply `np.array(out, dtype=np.unit8)`.